# wordpress frontend uploader for custom post types

Tags: wordpress, fine-uploader

I am not very experienced in WordPress, so this may be an easy question to ask, but I do not seem to be able to find the answer to my question.

I have a custom post type, lets call it foo_type and a custom taxonomy (category), lets call it foo_cat.
The foo_type has a title, a description and a media field (as custom fields). When a new foo_type needs to be created, It is necessary for it to have the title and a media. It is also required that the foo_type be selected from a list as well.

I need a frontend uploader plugin that can work with my custom post type and custom taxonomy in the following manner:
1- In the frontend upload form I need to load the foo_cat for the user to select from (for example in a drop-down list)
2- The form should also include a title and description area and the upload button
3- when a file is selected and the button is pressed, a new foo_type post should be created (with the selected foo_cat and the given title and description) and the uploaded media should be attached to this new post (foo type).

Is there any plugin that has the capability to accomplish what I want or should I get into code and create one? If I need to make one myself please also tell me where should I start.

Comment: Gravityforms does just that with the custom post type plugin, I used it a few times. Its a paid plugin however if that is not a problem for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use [Front-end Uploader](https://wordpress.org/plugins/frontend-uploader/) because of that plugin provides very good customization after the form submission.

Once you have done with the frontend forms , you need to store the data as you explained. For that you need to use their custom hook.

```
function my_fu_upload_result( $layout, $result ) {
    // do something
}
add_action(‘fu_upload_result’, ‘my_fu_upload_result’, 10, 2 );
```

Here you will get the submitted data and you can store then inside your custom post type by using `wp_insert_post` , [Link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) for reference.

Comment: Well, Thanks a lot! 
It seems like a perfect fit. I will use this method and let you know how it goes.

Comment: i tried the frontend uploader. It does not meet my requirements. I need the file to be uploaded after a foo_type post is created. 
The frontend uploader does not create any post and just uploads the media as an attachment.
Sure I can use the hook to create the post I want. However after the file is uploaded to the server it is too late.

Comment: After a few tweaks I managed to make frontend-uploader work. You can even add you own action to the source code. I used do_action('fu_pre_upload') to have a hook and do stuff just before the file is uploaded.